# How to give sentence case to sentences through CSS or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

How to give sentence case to sentences through CSS or javascript?

I've tried these CSS properties but these are different

```
capitalize    Transforms the first character of each word to uppercase
uppercase   Transforms all characters to uppercase
lowercase   Transforms all characters to lowercase
```

Edit: 19 FEB 2010

is there any option in jquery to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think CSS has enough programming power to recognize sentences. The methods I can think of don't work cross browser. You really should use Javascript (if it must be client side) or a serverside language to do this work.

Comment: A big problem with trying to do this is proper names and things that should have capital letters in the middle of a sentence are virtually impossible to detect, so even if you don't care about the performance hit it's problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use JavaScript to fix your content.  This is inefficient on a scale of ridiculous.  Write your content correctly before you publish it or use some coding scheme on the server side.  If this is some scheme to fix content that you don't control, such as user supplied, then simply state the content comes from your users and not you.

Seriously, this is going to delay the loading of your page significantly and cause visitors to abandon your site.

Comment: what if we are working on multilingual sites, with resources database, and dont want to insert ALL incidents of a sentence there? we need string manipulation

Comment: I agree with this as far as not running it on a public site because of the performance issues.  However, it is not on a scale of ridiculous if you are doing web applications with this applied to very few strings.  For instance: we have a project with little javascript "portlets."  We make the portlet titles out of the id of the portlet so my_reports becomes "My Reports".  I love not adding unnecessary objects if things have already been defined.  It also goes out and looks for the HTML to AJAX load something like "templates/" + id + ".htm"

Comment: I agree and disagree... It should not be the server's side to prepare data for presentation, unless there's a specific presentation layer present. Just like you should *not* be manually hardcoding HTML in your server-side code to be sent to the client; The "text-transform" property, as well as JavaScript, were introduced to take on those responsibilities. That being said, that is also the job for the *presentation layer* of the server. If you don't have one, implement one! But be sure to do so properly... you don't want to maintain code where you decided to mix business and presentation logic.

Answer (score 6):

```
p:first-letter{text-transform:capitalize}
```

Capitalizes the first word of each sentence

Comment: iirc, this only capitalizes the first word of each <p> tag. If you're like most people and don't wrap Every Single Sentence in a paragraph tag (because that is just a tad bit excessive and, logically, a paragraph does not always contain only one sentence), then this will not work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Something similar to this will work in JavaScript:

```
function sentenceCase(theText) {
    return theText.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\s*\w|[\.\!\?]\s*\w)/g,function(c){return c.toUpperCase()});

}
```

Won't work perfectly in ALL cases, but, it might get you somewhere. There are a lot more elegant solutions on back-end languages, typically, though.

Comment: pls give me a good js solution and tell me how to add

Comment: Three problems.

1) Your solution is perfect for text that is actually sentences, but can improperly interfere with text that is not sentences.

2) You are passing a function through a replace method.  This is the most serious non-AJAX security flaw in JavaScript as it can be used to execute malicious code if the code base is compromised on the server.  Compromising such code from legitimate web servers is common, low complexity, and rarely patched.

3) You have a typo.  The semicolon on the top line should not exist.

Comment: @austin, could u explain 2 again? Didn't understand that at all... How is passing a function to the replace() method a security concern???

Comment: @austin: 1) I actually even said that it won't work in all cases. It's a horrible solution especially when you consider that it's a horrible idea in the first place. Just thought I would answer the question. 2) I'm not passing a function to a replace, I'm passing a string to the replace method which uses a callback to manipulate the text. This is a very common and not a security issue. It's merely replacing the first character in the string to be uppercase. Maybe I don't quite get it but I don't see any chance of Cross-site-scripting or anything like that using something like this. 3) Fixed.

Comment: You are passing an anonymous function with an argument as the second argument of the replace method.  When passing a function through a replace method you are creating a hole by which malicious code can be piped in and automatically executed without an explicit call to the malicious code.  Considering all JavaScript is executed as text through an eval method at the interpreter it is completely open internally to injection attacks.  String injection in JavaScript is not typically a problem as it usually just causes the code to crash due to syntax violation or namespace collision.

Comment: i'm not clear on this - why wouldn't the method ALWAYS be called? where's the opportunity to inject just because it's an anonymous method? I assume you're thinking of a string like 'foo", <malicious code here>' but I don't see why the second item being an anonymous method call makes this any worse.

Comment: @austin I simply disagree with that being a security concern, but I do think it's not performance-savvy.

Answer (score 3):

what about:

```
str = "HeLlo Its aamiR here";
str = str.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+str.substr(1).toLowerCase()
```

Comment: This does not work for multiple sentences.