# css: capitalizing hard-coded uppercase text

Tags: css

I have content that is in uppercase ( that's the way it's persisted on the back end ) and I have to transform it into 'proper case'.

I'm finding out that 'text-transform:capitalize' doesn't work. I suspect there's no css based workaround for that either.

```
.text-test{
    text-transform:capitalize;
    } ... <h1 class="text-test">SOME UPPER CASE TEXT</h1>
```

Is my conclusion correct?
Thanks

Comment: Capitalise won't work as it targets on the first letter of whatever you're targeting so the rest of the text won't be affected. You'll have to edit it in the HTML or maybe a jQuery solution can be found,

Comment: Kyle, please post it as an answer, like to up-vote it. Unless you don't really care ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capitalise won't work as it targets on the first letter of whatever you're targeting so the rest of the text won't be affected. You'll have to edit it in the HTML or maybe a jQuery solution can be found,

I care :)

Answer (score 2):

CSS does not support sentence case conversion. Fix it in the server or you're going to have to use JavaScript to re-write the HTML.

See: [How to give sentence case to sentences through CSS or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504638/how-to-give-sentence-case-to-sentences-through-css-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

***Title Case***

```
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(t) {
        return t.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + t.substr(1).toLowerCase();}); 
};
var s1 = "HELLO WORLD!";
alert(s1.toTitleCase());
```

output

> Hello World!

This isn't as elegant as a solution that would say convert it to

> Hello world!

However I'm sure you can use this as a start point.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat very (very) late, but can help others.

What about:

```
.text-test {text-transform: lowercase;}
.text-test::first-letter {text-transform:capitalize;}
```